# Exact search in array object type using elasticsearch

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I'm looking for a way to do **exact** array matches in elastic search.
Let's say these are my documents:

```
{"id": 1, "categories" : ["c", "d"]}
{"id": 2, "categories" : ["b", "c", "d"]}
{"id": 3, "categories" : ["c", "d", "e"]}
{"id": 4, "categories" : ["d"]}
{"id": 5, "categories" : ["c", "d"]}
```

Is there a way to search for all document's that have **exactly** the categories "c" and "d" (documents 1 and 5), no more or less?

As a bonus: Searching for "one of these" categories should still be possible as well (for example you could search for "c" and get 1, 2, 3 and 5)

Any clever way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have a discrete, known set of categories, you could use a bool query:

```
"bool" : {
    "must" : {
        "terms" : { "categories" : ["c", "d"],
             minimum_should_match : 2
         }
    },
    "must_not" : {
        "terms" : { "categories" : ["a", "b", "e"],
             minimum_should_match : 1
         }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, Probably the easiest way to accomplish this, I think, is to store another field serving as a categories keyword.

```
{"id": 1, "categories" : ["c", "d"], "categorieskey" : "cd"}
```

Something like that.  Then you could easily query with a term query for precisely the results you want, like:

```
term { "categorieskey" : "cd" }
```

And you could still search non-exclusively, as;

```
term { "categories" : "c" }
```

Querying for two categories that must both be present is easy enough, but then preventing any other potential categories from being present is a bit harder.  You could do it, probably.  You'dd probably want to write a query to find records with both, then apply a filter to it eliminating any records with categories other than the ones specified.  It's not really a sort of search that Lucene is really designed to handle, to my knowledge.

Honestly I'm having a bit of trouble coming up with a good filter to use here.  You might need a script filter, or you could filter the results after they have been retrieved.

Comment: funny, that's exactly what i told him :)

Comment: This query won't run. `minimum_match` doesn't appear to be a valid parameter to a TermsFilter.

Comment: @Conrad.Dean Who said anything about using a filter?

Comment: @femtoRgon oh woops. i was way too zoomed in.  the syntax is identical if that's wrapped with a `"filter":{...}` instead of just a `"query":{...}`.  `minimum_should_match` is a valid parameter in a terms query  http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html

Comment: Ah, you're right, probably should be `minimum_should_match`.  Not sure whether that's a change in ElasticSearch, or a mistake, but certainly doesn't hurt to update. Thanks.

Comment: `terms` does not support `minimum_should_match`. It needs to be inside the `bool` query. The above query will not do what the OP wants and should not be marked as the best answer. The correct answer is to use one `terms` per term (a single-value array), and use `minimum_should_match` with the number of terms.

Comment: @AlexanderStaubo - Okay, that, I'm certain, is a [change in the API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-terms-query.html).  This question was asked in 2012, which would have been around the time 0.90 was released.  That change occurred in 2.0, 3 years *after* this question was asked and answered.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for our usage case that appears to work.  It relies on two filters and the knowledge of how many categories we want to match against. We make use of a terms filter and a script filter to check the size of the array. In this example, marketBasketList is similar to your categories entry.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "siteId": 4
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "marketBasketList": {
              "query": [
                10,
                11
              ],
              "operator": "and"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "boost": 1,
    "filter": {
      "and": {
        "filters": [
          {
            "script": {
              "script": "doc['marketBasketList'].values.length == 2"
            }
          },
          {
            "terms": {
              "marketBasketList": [
                10,
                11
              ],
              "execution": "and"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```