# How to choose from elasticsearch element that exactly matches the value of the array?

Tags: elasticsearch, yii2

Suppose the model has a list of fields, and one of them - id list some related fields:

```
{
    'name': 'bla-bla',
    'field1': 'value1',
    'array': [
        1, 2, 3, 4
    ]
}
```

Necessary select those records whose values coincide with the array transmits a set of id, i.e. if I give **1, 2, 3**, or vice versa **1, 2, 3, 4, 5**, the row will not find, but if you pass **3, 2, 4, 1** (i.e. the order does not address), the row should be found.

Comment: Pls take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12677414/2161778

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following using [`script`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html):

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "filter": {
    "script": {
      "script": "_source.array == [1, 2, 3, 4]"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know whether I can do this using [Yii2 ElasticSearch extension](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-elasticsearch)?